# Rounding error in SECOND function when converting hh:mm:ss.000 to milliseconds in Excel?

Tags: excel, rounding, milliseconds, seconds, rounding-error

I am trying to write a function to convert a column of times entered in a [hh]:mm:ss.000 format to milliseconds using the following function:

```
=MINUTE(C75)*60000+SECOND(C75)*1000+RIGHT(TEXT(C75, "hh:mm:ss.000"),3)
```

From playing around with the numbers with a calculator, I've deduced that the problem is that the SECOND() function is rounding to the nearest second based on the milliseconds rather than copying the exact value. For example, 00:17:39.320 will convert correctly, but 00:17:39.760 will not, as the function will convert the seconds using 40 rather than 39.

Does anyone know ways around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Then don't use `Second`.  Use the Right 6 characters × 1000

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. There might be something wrong with my number format because this also doesn't function also doesn't work properly. I used the format [hh]:mm:ss.000;@. The cell will look right when I type the value, but when I click it Excel converts the time to hh:mm:ss AM/PM in the formula bar and changes the value in the cell when I click away. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Excel support for time to ms resolution is, patchy.  Many (most?) Time functions work to seconds only.  Jim's suggestion to use the underlying numerical value is probably best.  Then you'll be left with the battle to deal with Excels desire to "helpfully" reformat the cells!

Answer (score 1):

Multiply your time by 86400000

```
=C75 * 86400000
```

Excel stores time as a fraction of a date.  12.00 noon will be .5 because its half of 24.  Therefore 24 hours times 60 minutes times 60 seconds give you total seconds times 1000 milliseconds gives your desired result.

Comment: This will give the correct number but it comes out in this format: 593360:00:00.000
(where 593360 is the correct number of ms). If I change the format to number or general, the calculations are no longer done correctly. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Try formatting to accounting or number with 0 decimals.